# Diskspace unaccounted for on azure managed mariadb

Tags: azure, mariadb, diskspace, mariadb-10.3

i have a managed Mariadb database (10.3.23) on Azure.

Azure tells me that 2.4tb of disk space is used yet when i check the databases i don't reach that figure.

```
select sum(data_length/1024/1024/1024) as data_length_gb, sum(data_free/1024/1024/1024) as data_free_gb  from information_schema.tables
```

returns

840.374844471924 and 257.385742187500 respectively.

what am i missing?

Comment: Did you have large temporary pages at some point (ref [MDEV-26782](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26782)). It might also have been that InnoDB files don't reduce in size, so deleting large amounts of data doesn't free disk space. Look (but don't touch)at the individual `ibd` files sizes and other files in MariaDB's data dir.

Comment: no temporary databases. being a managed azure database i don't have ssh access to look at the data dir.